# Make BottomNavigationItem Icon fill height

Tags: dart, flutter

Here is a image of my BottomNavigationBar.

[image]

There is white space underneath the icons.
How can I remove that white space and have the icon fill the space? I have tried passing an empty `Container` to the title property but the space is still there.

Here is my `BottomNavigationBar` code:

```
new BottomNavigationBar(
            items: [
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.grey),
                  title: new Container(),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white),
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.grey),
                  title: new Container(),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white),
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.add_circle, color: Colors.grey),
                  title: new Container(),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white),
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.grey),
                  title: new Container(),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white),
              new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.person_outline, color: Colors.grey),
                  title: new Container(),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white),
            ])
```

Comment: You can't, that is space for the title property to display text.

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this below**

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
child: new Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: <Widget>[
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {//code here},),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {//code here},),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {//code here},),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {//code here},),
  ],
),
),
```